# Visual Basic LinkLabel Customization

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, label

Ok, so basically I have a label and i want the user to be able to add a file location to it, for further access. Like.. he choses file A to be bound to Label1. So when he clicks Label1, file A will open..  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a code performing the actions you want:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim fd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
    Dim strFileName As String

    fd.InitialDirectory = "C:\"

    If fd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        LinkLabel1.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fd.FileName)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked
    Process.Start(LinkLabel1.Text)
End Sub
```

You have to add a button (`Button1`) and a linklabel (`LinkLabel1`) to your form and use this code.

Comment: thank you , that worked magic , but is it any way in which i can replace the label name? Seeing the file location there is pretty ugly..

Comment: You can affect the label as much as you want through LinkLabel1.Text it works like a normal string. You can trim the part you want or just show the filename (System.IO.Path.GetFileName()). Anything you can do with a string. Btw, are you Dani Mateo the famous one? haha

Comment: Haha i am not a famous singer , or I am that famous one and went bankrupt so started programming. Anyways, thanks for your answer , helped me a lot , but i am pretty new to VB, as you probably guessed , can you tell me about that filename function? An example would be really nice. Thanks once more.

Comment: It is straightforward, I have updated the code. This joke sounds to me like a Dani Mateo's original (he is an humourist in Spain).

Comment: Sounds like i have a comediants humour . Good to know . Code works perfect . Hope i'll get better in VB . Used to program in it but i forgot pretty much everything out of it . It's nice to have people around willing to help though

Comment: Ohh one more question. Will these changes to the linklabel be permanent? Or can I implement something like a Save button?

Comment: You haven't used VB very, very long time ago :) all these changes are performed at the runtime; that is, will be there while the program is running (and you don't assign a different value to LinkLabel1.Text). Every time the program is started it takes the default values for all the variables (for LinkLabel1 will be most likely LinkLabel1). You can change these starting values from the properties panel in the design view (where you created the button and the linklabel).

Comment: ok. Thanks . This was my final question , at least I hope

Answer (score 0):

You could save the user specified file location to `My.Settings` as a string. Then you can open the file in the on click event of the label with something like `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(My.Settings.Label1Path)`